# Strongly Influencing Electric & Magnetic Field Forces:

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields

Why is it easier to block electric field forces than magnetic field forces in close ranges to the source?

What is the best way to block, redirect, and minimize the strength of half of the lines of magnetic flux flowing into the pole of a permanent magnet (without completely blocking more than 1/2 the pole)?

Comment: mu-metal is often used in magnetic shielding

Comment: I've seen the MuMetal product info.  They offer fully annealed & stress annealed soft-temper foil & sheet material. UltraPerm is another brand that is available, but how would one calculate the magnetic attenuation of each product to determine how well they work?

Comment: Ask them for advise. They should have a lot of experience.